# Compare MySQL dates?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns, start and end.

I need to filter the results to ensure that today's date is between start and end. The date is stored in MM/DD/YYYY syntax. e.g. 02/05/2011

Can anyone show me how this is done please?

```
"SELECT * FROM albums WHERE active=1 AND ..."
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this your own schema? Can you convert the dates from plain text to actual dates?

Comment: The date is stored using wrong datatype. Use `DATETIME` or `DATE` to store dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    *
from 
    albums
where
    active=1
    and STR_TO_DATE(begin_date,'%m/%d/%Y') <= CURDATE()
    and CURDATE() <= STR_TO_DATE(end_date,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

But dates shouldn't be stored as `varchar`. They should be stored as `date`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM albums 
WHERE active=1 
AND (Comare_Value) between Start and End
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM albums
    WHERE active=1
        AND start <= NOW()
        AND end >= NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    albums
WHERE
    active=1 
    AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date;
```